# Configure ShowVideoPlaceholders to 'false' in DXA website

Tags: configuration, dxa

How can I make 'SiteConfiguration.MediaHelper.ShowVideoPlaceholders' equal to false?

The constructor of Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.BaseMediaHelper seems to hardcode this to 'true'.

Comment: Is it not as simple as putting SiteConfiguration.MediaHelper.ShowVideoPlaceholders = false; in Application_Start() in global.asax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can simply set this property to false in the Application_Start method of your web application global.asax. You can either directly edit the version provided with the DXA (see penultimate line in code example below), or inherit from it and override it.

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        InitializeDependencyInjection();
        SiteConfiguration.StaticFileManager = (IStaticFileManager)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IStaticFileManager));
        SiteConfiguration.MediaHelper = (IMediaHelper)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IMediaHelper));
        SiteConfiguration.Initialize(TridionConfig.PublicationMap);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        SiteConfiguration.MediaHelper.ShowVideoPlaceholders = false;
        initialized = true;
    }
```

Comment: True. Weird, but true. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The value is indeed hard-coded to `true` in BaseMediaHelper, so if you want to use `false`, you will have to create your own subclass which sets it to `false` and register your class instead of BaseMediaHelper in `Unity.config`.

Comment: Thanks very much Rick. Indeed this is possible. I created 'ExtendedDD4TMediaHelper' inheriting from 'BaseMediaHelper' then in the constructor I call the base and set 'base.ShowVideoPlaceholders = false;'.Then, as you said, updated my unity config to use my new class. Note: You must implement all methods already defined in the original e.g. I made a direct copy of 'GetResponsiveImageUrl'. It feels a little dirty but is necessary.

Comment: Can you not subclass DD4TMediaHelper and override the constructor only?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.